# C# with database server application without using DataSets

Tags: c#, database, datatable, dataset

Is there a way to create an application using C# with any database server, but without using DataSets, DataTables, DataAdapters, and so on? (in this case, without using DataGridView too)

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at the Entity Framework.

Comment: Do you mean you want one class to deal with various data bases (ie SQL Server, MySQL, ect.)?

Comment: Does DataReader count in the things you do not want to use ?  DataReader is much faster and uses less memory then the other options you mentioned

Comment: "and so on" meaning all of ADO.NET?

Comment: evanmcdonnal: not exactly a program that fits exatly in many data bases (I mean, without changing any part of the code) or at the same time... It could be MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL

Comment: Scott: I believe that the use of a datareader can be desconsidered in this application. It is basically a CRUD, not much... What do you think about it?

Comment: You could use ODBC and linked servers in SQL, you could use NHibernate - question is, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

You can use ADO.Net EntityFramework to work with database without DataSets. Or you can use any other ORM.